# How to make <p:ajaxStatus> display steadily for and between two requests?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Following a user's action I have two quite consecutive ajax requests whose status I am indicating via `<p:ajaxStatus>`. But as between them there is a bit happening on client side (no user action required) there is a little break in displaying the ajax status indication.

Is there a way to close this gap?

**UPDATE:**
I tried KidTempo's proposal using another `<p:remoteCommand>` to perform an `async=true` Ajax request with the following `actionListener` and it seems to work now:

```
public void sleep(ActionEvent ae) throws InterruptedException{
    setAddressProcessingFinished(false);
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    while(addressProcessingFinished == false){
        thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at async=true ajax requests? (so the other ajax requests can run at the same time)

You could have an ajax request that sleeps until your second ajax request finishes. I think the ajaxStatus indication should then be active throughout.

```
sleepyAjax (until bean.finished==true)
|
|  yourAjax_1
|  yourAjax_2 (set bean.finished = true)
V
sleepyAjax Finished!
```

note: haven't tried this, it may not work this way but I'd be interested to know if it does...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, I thought about "wrapping" the two Ajax requests into a third, too. But I didn't like the idea of the overhead it produces.

Comment: @Lester do you mean the overhead in terms of processing? Putting a sleep(1000) in a loop until bean.finished==true should take almost no overhead. (Remember to set a timeout).

Comment: This isn't quite the same as wrapping - it's three separate ajax requests but sleepyAjax is "long-lived" so to speak

Comment: I meant overhead in terms of number of requests. I just tried to implement this but although the Thread sleeps the Ajax indicator disappears too fast. Funny: The effect I wish I get with a breakpoint a the sleepyAjax's actionListener because the other Threads go on.

Comment: In debug I noticed that `addressProcessingFinished` was already true at the begin of the `while`-loop. Can happen in a `SessionScoped` bean. I moved `setAddressProcessingFinished(false)` before the loop instead of after (for the next time - what a bad idea). Now it seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: @Lester yeah, understanding phases will help you a lot. Just search BalusC and jsf phases and you should find lots of articles and answers that will teach most of what you need to know. ProTip: BalusC knows all...

Comment: Yeah he does. Just worked through his "Debug JSF Lifecycle"-Post (again) some days ago. The last problem was not about phases I suppose. It was just working because I worked on the code and at some point setting that bean value to `true` without going through all the code that was planned. And then because the bean was `SessionScoped` I worked with that value that I thought to be `false`but indeed was `true`. But the good side: If I had simply redeployed I might not have noticed that weakness in the code.